# Android RGB to YCbCr Conversion and output to imageView

Tags: android, image

I am doing an image processing which require to convert RGB bitmap image to YCbCr color space. I retrieved RGB value for each pixel and apply the conversion matrix to it.

```
public void convertRGB (View v) {
    if (imageLoaded) {
        int width = inputBM.getWidth();
        int height = inputBM.getHeight();

        int pixel;
        int alpha, red, green, blue;
        int Y,Cb,Cr;

        outputBM = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, inputBM.getConfig());

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                pixel = inputBM.getPixel(x, y);
                alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
                red = Color.red(pixel);
                green = Color.green(pixel);
                blue = Color.blue(pixel);

                Y  =  (int) (0.299     *  red + 0.587  * green + 0.114 * blue);
                Cb =  (int) (128-0.169 *   red-0.331   * green + 0.500 * blue);
                Cr =  (int) (128+0.500 *   red - 0.419 * green - 0.081 * blue);

                int p = (Y << 24) | (Cb << 16) | (Cr<<8);

                outputBM.setPixel(x,y,p);

            }
        }
        comImgView.setImageBitmap(outputBM);
    }
}
```

The problem is he output color is different with original. I tried to use BufferedImage but it do not work in Android

Original:

[image: Original]

After Conversion:

[image: After Convert]

May I know what is the correct way to handle YCbCr image in android java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting using below code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(your_yuv_data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);
byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
iv.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Check documentation for detailed description for [YuvImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html#YuvImage(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[])) Class.

Comment: I tried this setting and get D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null error. May I know what exactly is the your_yuv_data?

Comment: it will be byte[] from your camerapreview